# React Native run on device iOS crash

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, device

I'm trying to run my react native app on my iPhone 6, but when it goes in the debug phase it crashes, but there are no problems on running it on simulator.

My react native version is 0.60.5

These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {<br>
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.1.5",<br>
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",<br>
    "react": "16.8.6",<br>
    "react-native": "^0.60.5",<br>
    "react-native-auth0": "^1.5.0",<br>
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.210.0",<br>
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.3.2",<br>
    "react-native-document-picker": "git://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker.git#v3",<br>
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.0.0",<br>
    "react-native-fs": "^2.14.1",<br>
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",<br>
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.0.2",<br>
    "react-native-offline": "^5.0.0",<br>
    "react-native-progress": "^3.6.0",<br>
    "react-native-queue": "^1.2.1",<br>
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",<br>
    "react-native-svg": "^9.6.4",<br>
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",<br>
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",<br>
    "realm": "^2.29.2",<br>
    "redux": "^4.0.4"<br>
  },<br>
  "devDependencies": {<br>
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",<br>
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",<br>
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",<br>
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",<br>
    "eslint": "^6.2.0",<br>
    "jest": "^24.9.0",<br>
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",<br>
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"<br>
  },<br>
```

And this is the full log:

```
2019-08-26 17:02:18.721172+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] [Accessibility] ****************** Loading GAX Client Bundle ****************
2019-08-26 17:03:18.996939+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] Task <9BC4C6D4-EA36-4C9E-AE26-EA910C6A991F>.<1> finished with error - code: -1001
2019-08-26 17:03:19.030974+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] Task <9BC4C6D4-EA36-4C9E-AE26-EA910C6A991F>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2019-08-26 17:03:19.027 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:236] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x103b13170> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x283f536b0>, executor: (null))
2019-08-26 17:03:19.037682+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x103b13170> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x283f536b0>, executor: (null))
2019-08-26 17:03:19.214 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:293] Running application iDiary ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2019-08-26 17:03:19.214706+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] Running application iDiary ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2019-08-26 17:03:19.299503+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] [NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x281472f00, domain=1, instance=1>
2019-08-26 17:03:19.551522+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] [NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x281469300, domain=1, instance=1>
2019-08-26 17:03:19.785 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:1061] Invalidating <RCTCxxBridge: 0x103b13170> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x283f536b0>, executor: RCTWebSocketExecutor)
2019-08-26 17:03:19.786216+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] Invalidating <RCTCxxBridge: 0x103b13170> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x283f536b0>, executor: RCTWebSocketExecutor)
2019-08-26 17:03:20.091 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `5` (method ID) on `WebSocketModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.091389+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `5` (method ID) on `WebSocketModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.097 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `5` (method ID) on `WebSocketModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.097325+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `5` (method ID) on `WebSocketModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.097 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `5` (method ID) on `WebSocketModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.097585+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `5` (method ID) on `WebSocketModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.098 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `5` (method ID) on `WebSocketModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.097817+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `5` (method ID) on `WebSocketModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.098 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `1` (method ID) on `WebSocketModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.098149+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `1` (method ID) on `WebSocketModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.098 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `0` (method ID) on `BlobModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.098306+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `0` (method ID) on `BlobModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.329 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `4` (method ID) on `BlobModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.328815+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `4` (method ID) on `BlobModule` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.362 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] [SECURITY] node-uuid: crypto not usable, falling back to insecure Math.random()
2019-08-26 17:03:20.362037+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] [SECURITY] node-uuid: crypto not usable, falling back to insecure Math.random()
2019-08-26 17:03:20.376 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager via UIManager['getConstants'] is no longer supported. Use UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('getConstants') instead.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.375708+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager via UIManager['getConstants'] is no longer supported. Use UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('getConstants') instead.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.437 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: src/navigation/AppNavigator.js -> src/components/SideMenu.js -> src/navigation/AppNavigator.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.437272+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Require cycle: src/navigation/AppNavigator.js -> src/components/SideMenu.js -> src/navigation/AppNavigator.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.541 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result.viewConfig')
2019-08-26 17:03:20.541567+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result.viewConfig')
2019-08-26 17:03:20.564 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `1` (method ID) on `ExceptionsManager` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.564373+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `1` (method ID) on `ExceptionsManager` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.573 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `0` (method ID) on `Timing` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.573063+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `0` (method ID) on `Timing` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.586 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Bundle was not loaded from the packager
2019-08-26 17:03:20.586445+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Bundle was not loaded from the packager
2019-08-26 17:03:20.587 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `1` (method ID) on `Timing` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.587586+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `1` (method ID) on `Timing` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.593 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2019-08-26 17:03:20.593304+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2019-08-26 17:03:20.601 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `1` (method ID) on `ExceptionsManager` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.601356+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `1` (method ID) on `ExceptionsManager` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.602 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `0` (method ID) on `Timing` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.601715+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `0` (method ID) on `Timing` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.610 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Bundle was not loaded from the packager
2019-08-26 17:03:20.609688+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Bundle was not loaded from the packager
2019-08-26 17:03:20.610 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTNativeModule.mm:86] Attempted to invoke `1` (method ID) on `Timing` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:20.610356+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Attempted to invoke `1` (method ID) on `Timing` (NativeModule name) without a method queue.
2019-08-26 17:03:30.614 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTCxxBridge.mm:1108] Timed out waiting for modules to be invalidated
2019-08-26 17:03:30.614340+0200 iDiary[14898:1856934] Timed out waiting for modules to be invalidated
2019-08-26 17:04:19.798616+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] Task <EC7C12E8-0C02-4260-906B-5BE0B9224C15>.<2> finished with error - code: -1001
2019-08-26 17:04:19.801 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:236] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x103b269c0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x283f536b0>, executor: RCTWebSocketExecutor)
2019-08-26 17:04:19.801222+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x103b269c0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x283f536b0>, executor: RCTWebSocketExecutor)
2019-08-26 17:04:19.803884+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] Task <EC7C12E8-0C02-4260-906B-5BE0B9224C15>.<2> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2019-08-26 17:04:19.834 [error][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:502] Unable to find module for AccessibilityManager
2019-08-26 17:04:19.833846+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] Unable to find module for AccessibilityManager
2019-08-26 17:04:19.840714+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-08-26 17:04:19.847779+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-08-26 17:04:19.848193+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-08-26 17:04:19.849213+0200 iDiary[14898:1856835] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C3] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2019-08-26 17:04:19.849290+0200 iDiary[14898:1856835] TCP Conn 0x28215a7c0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2019-08-26 17:04:19.856 [error][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:502] Unable to find module for EventDispatcher
2019-08-26 17:04:19.855794+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] Unable to find module for EventDispatcher
2019-08-26 17:04:19.856171+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4.2:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-08-26 17:04:19.857102+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] TIC TCP Conn Failed [4:0x28215ae80]: 1:61 Err(61)
2019-08-26 17:04:19.859256+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] Task <41F50C0D-6D7D-4438-99AC-A58F0678DBF7>.<3> HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2019-08-26 17:04:19.859761+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] Task <41F50C0D-6D7D-4438-99AC-A58F0678DBF7>.<3> finished with error - code: -1004
2019-08-26 17:04:19.868 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=client timed out. Are you running node proxy? If you are running on the device, check if you have the right IP address in `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`.
2019-08-26 17:04:19.868264+0200 iDiary[14898:1857060] Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=client timed out. Are you running node proxy? If you are running on the device, check if you have the right IP address in `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`.
2019-08-26 17:04:19.869 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.WebSocketExecutor][RCTWebSocketExecutor.m:145] WebSocket connection failed with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2019-08-26 17:04:19.868969+0200 iDiary[14898:1856834] WebSocket connection failed with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2019-08-26 17:04:19.881896+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] *** Assertion failure in -[RCTCxxBridge ensureOnJavaScriptThread:](), /Users/dev/Desktop/iDiary/app-mobile/iDiary/node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm:293
2019-08-26 17:04:19.882588+0200 iDiary[14898:1856748] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This method must not be called before the JS thread is created'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x188bad27c 0x187d879f8 0x188ac6988 0x1895d6ee8 0x10083199c 0x10083a1b0 0x103a3f6f0 0x103a40c74 0x103a4e6fc 0x188b3ec1c 0x188b39b54 0x188b390b0 0x18ad3979c 0x1b536f978 0x10072817c 0x1885fe8e0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Hope anyone knows how to solve it, thanks in advance

Answer (score 15):

Ok, apparently was just a problem of connection, my iPhone wasn't connected to the same wifi as my macbook and so it didn't worked

Comment: This was the last thing i've ever expected, I thought a USB connection is enough.

Answer (score 3):

Check your Wi-Fi connections:

- Make sure your iOS device is connected to the same WiFi your macOS development machine is connected to.

Symptoms of different Wi-Fi connections:

- Your Metro Bundler terminal is blank
- Your app is hung at start-up
- react native xcode debugging timed out waiting for modules to be invalidated